# CSS: Selecting an specific son with conditions

Tags: html, css

I need to find the son of *super-dad* that doesn't have a **x-hidden** class and if I find it, make sure it's **unique**, as you can see below (second-son).

**Right:**

```
<div class="super-dad">
 <div class="first-son x-hidden"> </div>
 <div class="second-son"> </div>
 <div class="third-son x-hidden"> </div>
</div>
```

> Find second-son.

**Wrong:**

```
<div class="super-dad">
 <div class="first-son x-hidden"> </div>
 <div class="second-son"> </div>
 <div class="third-son"> </div>
</div>
```

> No match in here.

Im working with **CSS**. 
The CSS should looks like:

*find a child of super-dad that its not hidden and apply this style if there is just one*

`.super-dad:someCSSexpression{ border-botton: 0; }`

Comment: it's not clear what you whant to achieve,,,

Comment: what do you mean exactly by unique?

Comment: He means the parent needs to have only one child that doesn't have the x-hidden class

Comment: Still not clear for me....

Comment: I think he wants to find the only child div without the x-hidden class... Using CSS...

Comment: It's not possible ONLY with CSS

Comment: This is not a duplicate at all.

Comment: Use javascript, i think (could be wrong) that this kind of 'conditional logic' is not possible in CSS...

Comment: All you could do with CSS is something like this: http://jsbin.com/dabuvikano/edit?html,css,output

Comment: any idea for SASS?

Comment: @GiacomoPaita yes, I saw it but It doesn't works for me.